# Disable forces once a force graph is displayed

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I am drawing a directed graph: [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/tepawoviya/1/edit?html,output). I want the graph to be initially displayed with forces, but then users can move freely the nodes. There are two options, any of them is fine for me:

1) Once the graph is displayed, I want to be able to drag any node to any position, the **force** does not intervene; the length of the links will be automatically adjusted

2) Once the graph is displayed, I want to be able to drag nodes, the length of the links could remain always the same, but I don't want the **force** to intervene to automatically change the position of other nodes.

I tried to modify `.charge(-300)`, but it does not work well, cold anyone help?

**Edit 1:**

I added `force.nodes([])`: [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/tivutaruli/1/edit?html,output), but it does not work as expected...

Comment: There might be two more approaches different from what was suggested by Mark's answer. Which one to choose largely depends on 1) Do you want the drag behaviour while the force is still running or just after it has come to a halt? 2) Will the force layout ever be reheated after it has come to an intial halt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am going to solve for this:

*1) Once the graph is displayed, I want to be able to drag any node to any position, the force does not intervene; the length of the links will be automatically adjusted*

First:

When you make your rectangle or circle as nodes then give it a class like this:

```
var circlesOrRects = svg.append("g").selectAll(".foo")
.data(force.nodes())
.enter()
.append("path")
.attr("class", "foo")//give it a class
```

Next after the force directed graph stops, fix the nodes like shown below:

```
var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
    .links(links)
    .size([width, height])
    .linkDistance(150)
    .charge(-300)
    .on("tick", tick)
    .start()
    .on("end", function(p) {
      //using the class for selecting nodes.
      d3.selectAll(".foo").each(function(d){
        d.fixed=true;//thsi will fix the node.
      });
    });
```

Now after the force has stopped you can drag your nodes anywhere.

Please note, that the **end** event will be triggred once the force alpha becomes 0, only then the nodes be fixed.

working code [here](https://jsbin.com/jegowifoya/1/edit?html,output)

Comment: There is one drawback, though: This will not stop the force from being reheated on every drag, it just fixes the nodes' positions. If there are many nodes in the layout, this might have a noticable influence on the overall performance.

Answer (score 0):

To manually stop a force directed graph you can simply call `force.stop()`.

What you've described is preventing the force from re-running when you make any changes. There are a few ways you could do this, I think probably the best would be to "detatch" the nodes from the force directed graph.

To do this simply call `force.nodes([])`. Now the force directed graph is working with an empty graph, and you can continue to use your nodes. To do this after the initial layout you'd want:

```
force.on("end", function() {
    force.nodes([]);
});
```

Comment: It is worth mentioning, that this only holds true for D3 v3, which, however, is what OP asked for. In v3 the force's own drag reheated the force on every drag event. In v4 the force layout got decoupled from the drag behaviour resulting in the drag events not reheating the layout. I have seen at least one question around asking for the exact opposite when using v4: *"why does my simulation not run on dragging?"*

Comment: @altocumulus thanks very much for that clarification. I've not yet had a chance to use v4 of the force - hadn't realized that behavior had changed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't see where to put `force.on("end...`. I put it in the end of the JavaScript script, it did not work...